# What package is /home/pi/python_games coming from?

Tags: python, dpkg

I tried to find the package with

```
dpkg -S tetromino.py
```

(tetromino.py is a file inside the folder) but there seems to be no package, that installed it. I also tried other files inside the directory. I know that I can just delete the folder, but I'd be interested, what packages installed it in the first place.

Comment: Note that very/most often removing a package does not remove files created post-installation by the app in `/home` directories -- i.e., they are left there for you to delete, keep around, etc.  So if you believe you do know where this likely came from and have already uninstalled it, you can go ahead and delete that directory.  Even if you haven't uninstalled it, the next time you use it will probably be re-created if necessary, or some clear error thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> there seems to be no package, that installed it

If it was a Raspbian package that installed it, either it was created post-installation or it comes from a repo which is not indexed properly.

```
> sudo apt install apt-file
[...]
> apt-file update
```

If the last command is new to you it is necessary to use "update" the first time (and occasionally thereafter) because the searches are performed on a local database.  It takes a few minutes, during which time on Raspbian there is output *perhaps* implying that some repos are not indexed -- however I don't know enough about it to confirm that, and I have not investigated.  Anyway:

```
apt-file search 'tetromino.py'
```

No result.  [Here are the results](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tetromino.py&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) for a similar online search of Debian's jessie stable, all architectures (i.e., including the basis of Raspbian).

I also tried "tetramino.py" in case there was a minor typo in your question.

Note these searches include all *available* packages, not just all currently installed ones (as per `dpkg -S`).

> /home/pi/python_games

Strongly implies it was created post-installation since packages in general do not include any files that go into particular user home directories, or home directories period.  However, many applications create such things the first time you use them.

Sometimes these things are just copied from a system wide directory (e.g., in `/usr/share/foo`) but since the searches did not turn anything up, this filename is not a very useful clue (except perhaps to someone familiar with the application)...

## ...or if you use an internet search engine...

In which case it is clear this is a tetris clone used as an example in an online book about programming games with pygame.  That *may* involve a Raspbian package, in which case you likely have some idea which one it was.

Comment: Not to be rude, but how exactly does that answer my question? No, the filename was not a typo and as I mentioned, I tried most of the files in the directory. This whole directory is inside pi's home directory after a standard installation using NOOBS. I wanted to know, what package it came from.

Comment: That's fine.  I was not trying to be condescending, just pointing out if it came from a package, you won't find it by searching, and 1) There is a decent chance it *did not* come from a Raspbian package, which is an answer to your question, or 2) There is a hypothesis in the last sentence (just edited in, ending: "you likely have some idea which one it was") which is about as close as you are going to get to answer without someone who happens to be familiar with the package strolling by.  Which may happen at any point, or never.

Comment: Finally, there's the "Raspbian specific repos not properly indexed issue", which if true is an answer to *why* you can't find it by searching.   All apologies if information garnered by "process of elimination" is completely useless -- but generally it does go some way toward a "complete answer".